# Improving speed of regex and using preg_replace for slugs

Tags: php, regex, slug

Previously I have been echoing $obj->html but a current project requires that the HTML be examined for slugs like `{whatever}` and replacing these with other content.

I have two problems.  The first is that this code is slower than I would like:

```
class Foo {

  function draw_content() {
    $slug = "/(?<=\{).*(?=\})/";
    if (preg_match($slug, $this->html, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            if (method_exists($this,$match))    {
                $replacement = $this->$match();
                $this->html = preg_replace("/\{$match\}/", $replacement, $this->html);
            }
        }
    } 
    return $this->html;
 } // fn

  function new_releases() {
    echo "new release book covers"; 
  }  // fn

} // class
```

Is there a better way to get the slug contents?  I presume the regex is what is slowing this down?

The second issue is stranger to me.  Given this $obj->html:

```
<p class="headline">New Releases</p>
<p>xxx{new_releases}xxxx</p>
```

The processed output of $obj->draw_content() is drawn by `<?=$obj->draw_content()?>`

```
new release book covers<p class="headline">New Releases</p>
<p>xxxxxxx</p>
```

Why is the `new_releases()` output prepended?  The slug is gone but the replacement is not in it's place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace your pattern by:

```
$slug = '~{\K[^}]*+(?=})~';
```

IMHO, you should replace your `preg_match` test and your `preg_replace` by an only `preg_replace_callback` function, try something like this (and correct the bugs :).

```
function draw_content() {
    $slug = '~{([^}]*+)}~';
    $that = $this;
    $this->html = preg_replace_callback( $slug, function ($m) use ($that) {
        if (method_exists($that, $m[1]))
            return $that->$m[1]();
        return $m[0]; }, $this->html);
    return $this->html;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is waaaay faster!  Thank you!  Any opinion on the weird preg_replace() behavior?

Comment: You rock!!  I was scratching my head over the `preg_replace_callback()` docs.  That absolutely solved my problems!

Comment: @jerrygarciuh: happy for you.

Comment: Sooo I have one more question- the server is running PHP  5.3.13; Docs say $this is not available in anon funcs until 5.4 http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php  Do I replace with a named func?  I tried making a global and cloning $this into it but no dice; not scoped for the anon func.

Comment: Now I owe you many many beers!  You have vastly improved my day!